# removing items from jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete (i must admit i haven't used it many times before), in order to allow the user to select multiple elements from a list.

When the user selects a value i update (push) the selected value in an array (AR1).

I need to be able to update the array (AR1) when a value is removed from the list of elements in the UI widget (component).

What happens when the user deletes a value? Don't think i can update my array (AR1).

I have thought of iterating the list of selected elements when the input loses focus and update the array then. But how do i iterate through the list of selected items?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jquery, you can loop through an array with:

```
$(arraVar).each(function(index, value){ 
  //do whatever here
}
```